# Unity editor not recognising a reference added in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to run a MATLAB file from a C# script that's an asset of a Unity Project, which requires the MLApp reference. After adding it and writing my script I get no errors in Visual Studio but the Unity Editor keeps showing 'The type or namespace 'MLApp' could not be found'

I'm aware that MLApp is meant for COM console applications so I made a new project (console application) with a void that executes the MATLAB script. After copying the file to the directory with the Unity project and using this.GetComponent to execute it I get the same error in the Unity Editor.

Comment: Unity generates a Visual Studio project as a convenience for you so you can edit your code more easily. It doesn't use that project at all to compile the code in the editor. You need to add the reference in Unity. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.